# How to rotate logs with rsyslog advanced format?

Tags: logging

I'm using rsyslog with `advanced` format (also known as RainerScript).  How can I make it rotate log files using this syntax?  My (simplified) config looks like this:

```
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514" ruleset="forward")
ruleset(name="forward") {
  action(type="omfwd" protocol="tcp" target="127.0.0.1" port="40514" TCP_Framing="octet-counted" KeepAlive="on" action.resumeRetryCount="-1" queue.type="linkedlist" queue.size="50000")
  action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/rsyslog_debug.log" Template="RSYSLOG_DebugFormat")
}
```

All the examples I've found show who to do it in the `basic` format like this, which works but is not compatible with the `advanced` format shown above.

```
$outchannel log_rotation,/var/log/log_rotation.log,52428800,/apps/syslogagent/rotation.sh
*.* :omfile:$log_rotation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported as of now.
Please take a look at the issue on Github from the author of Rsyslog

https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/2479

Comment: Also on this confirmation https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/2852#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20outchannel%20is%20only%20available%20in%20legacy%20config:~:text=Now%20I%20am%20in%20the%20search%20too.%20My%20idea%20was%20that%20Output%20Channels%20became%20a%20legacy%20and%20thus%20aren%27t%20being%20integrated%20into%20the%20RainerScript%20parser%20anyway%3A

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).